# Debugging Windows 6.1 mobile using Visual Studio 2008 in Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile-6

I have to develop a Mobile application in Windows 6.1. I am using Widnows 7 in my Desktop. My physical device is not detected in the Desktop. I tried using Windows Mobile Device Center. How can i debug using Visual Studio 2008 and the physical device in Widows 7 Desktop. What should i do. If i install Virtual PC ,should i run VS 2008 inside virtual PC ?

Comment: Possibly you have a firewall problem. WMDC will connect a debug port with Windows Mobile 6 devices normally. You may try to disable "Enhanced network..." on device in settings-connections-UsbToPC. This option switches between RNDIS and PPP connection. I have also seen cases where ActiveSync was disabled on device. Here is a MSDN trouvleshooting guide for AS/WMDC: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/915152?wa=wsignin1.0